# Setting selected values from controller not working in multi-select dropdown

Tags: angularjs

In my angular app there is a multi-select dropdown.Currently using `https://github.com/amitava82/angular-multiselect`.But when setting selected options from inside controller.The placeholder shows like "3 Selected",but the checkboxes associated with the options are not checked.My html is

```
<am-multiselect class="" multiple="true" ms-selected ="There are {{oldtag.length}} tags are selested"
   ng-model="oldtag" ms-header="Choose Incentive Pay"
   options="oldtag as oldtag.tag_name for oldtag in masterTagList"
   change="selected()">
</am-multiselect>
```

In my controller

```
 $scope.masterTagList = [{
    "tag_id": 1,
    "tag_name": "fish"
 }, {
    "tag_id": 2,
    "tag_name": "meat"
 }, {
    "tag_id": 3,
    "tag_name": "egg"
 }];
 $scope.oldtag = [{
    "tag_id": 1,
    "tag_name": "fish"
 }];
```

Comment: There's a lot of instances of `oldtag` there..

Comment: @Ankh Sorry I diidn't get you? and please help me to solve this.Is there a problem in "oldTag" as model  and ng-options

Comment: If your model is `oldtag` then you should not use the same name in the `options` attribute

Comment: Is that the reason that do not show checkbox ?

Comment: Without trying I don't know, it's a suggestion hence me not posting as an answer. I suggest you try it yourself.

Comment: I Changed the name of model.But still it is not working

Comment: Anybody know the answer please help me.

Comment: Please give me a solution.Its urgent and today is my projects first release.